# Where can I see Chrome Remote Desktop's connection log?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, google-chrome, logging, chrome-remote-desktop

Where can I see [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrome_Remote_Desktop)'s connection log (i.e., given a Chrome Remote Desktop host computer, see the list of connections that accessed the host computer)?

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1649523?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en, *When that person enters your access code on the site, you will see a dialog with their e-mail address. Select Share to allow them full access to your computer*

Comment: @NekoMusume thanks! Where can I see Chrome Remote Desktop's connection log?